# Avoid regex backtracking while parsing big files

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, backtracking

I'm parsing some files that meets a pattern to produce an human readable report. I use regex in order to parse that files.

#### Example of file:

```
2012-05-10 08:00:00.155: BROADCAST - Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Data></Data>. MessageProperties [headers={X_Day=20120510}]
2012-05-10 08:00:00.155: BROADCAST - Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Data></Data>. MessageProperties [headers={X_Day=20120510}]
2012-05-10 08:00:00.155: REQUEST - Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <field1>field1.val</field1>
  <field2>field2.val</field2>
</Data>. MessageProperties [headers={X_Day=20120510}, correlationId=[51, 56, 100, 54, 48, 48, 97, 54, 51, 99, 102, 100, 52, 102, 97, 51, 98, 51, 57, 52, 52, 49, 49, 50, 54, 97, 56, 100, 49, 48, 53, 98], other=blabla]
```

I want to extract the time part, the xml part and the properties part of each record.

#### Regex

Currently I have this regex expression which gives me what I want (*I have no problem in do a later processing to extract the exact bits a need if that can help with the speed of the regex*):

```
((?:[0-9]{1,4}[-| |:|\.])+[0-9]{1,3}): .*Body: ((?:.|>\n|>\r|>\r\n)*\. MessageProperties )(\[.*\])
```

The files can be big (Like 2000-10000 matches and 100Mb) so I want to optimize it a little. The current problem is all the **backtracking** I have with that .* before body and (?:.|>\n|>\r\n)* before MessageProperties (I need to include the line breaks explicitly for the third example record I gave).

Is there any way to optimize all this backtracking? I couldn't find a way.

I'm using **regex101** to develop it and then I adjust it to **.Net**.

Comment: Honestly if you're looking for performance you might want to write your own parsing code and forget about regex.

Comment: I don't want to optimize it that hard, and I think that this regex can be optimize easily. currently I'm getting a second to parse a file, but with half a second or so I'm fine.

Comment: Specifically are you applying that regex to the entire file?  If so I'd at least suggest reading one line from the file at a time and adding that line to a buffer.  When you see a line that starts with the date then process the lines in the buffer, clear the buffer, and add the new line.

Comment: Learn to use character classes. `(:|-|=)+` should be written as `[:=-]+`.

Comment: Thanks @juharr for the advice, If no one post another answer maybe i'll go that way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated using it, but it didn't saved any step. Also, the performance problem is with the backtracking, any suggest to deal with it?

Comment: A hint: do not *test* .NET regex performance in a PCRE environment. .NET is much more stable and powerful in this regard. Better download Ultrapico Expresso (no affiliation) and test .NET regexes there. You may use regex101 to *sketch* a pattern for .NET, but you can't expect the same "user experience" when using it in .NET.

Comment: Might start the regex with `\n`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/zrfdsO/1. Or a much faster - https://regex101.com/r/zrfdsO/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In fact,I test the performance in .Net and use regex101 for sketching. I'm trying your updated solutions. I have a problem with [^][]* since the chars [] can be in the message properties. Updated example. I you do an answer I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Finally I used ([0-9]{4}-[- :.0-9]*): [^-]*\s+-\s+Body: ([^.]*(?:\.(?!\s+MessageProperties\s)[^.]*)*\.\s+MessageProperties\s+)(\[.*]) . It improved it by a 10x factor, so its perfect. I take note of your optimizations.

Comment: If you have a balanced amount of brackets in message properties, you can't rely on PCRE tester. Use `^([0-9]{4}-[- :.0-9]*): [^-]*\s+-\s+Body: ([^.]*(?:\.(?!\s+MessageProperties\s)[^.]*)*\.\s+MessageProperties\s+)(\[(?>[^][]|(?<x>)\[|(?<-x>)])*](?(x)(?!)))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The version with .* seems to be much faster that the latest one (4x factor)

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez you can't compare apples to pears. These are different regexps. If you have nested balanced brackets you must use the right pattern to match them. Unless you are dead sure you just need to match the `[` and then all chars on the line up to and including the las `]` on that line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I only need the text between the first and latest bracket, so I think I shouldn't care about balancing them, right?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General Tips and Improvements

Try to avoid single character alternations, quantify the parts to the right rather than parts to the left and use character classes wherever possible. The unknown texts between two strings are better unrolled using the [unroll the loop principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) (that is, do not use `.*` or `.*?` even when you are tempted to do so).

## Your Solution

You may use

```
^([0-9]{4}-[- :.0-9]*):\s+[^-]*\s+-\s+Body:\s+([^.]*(?:\.(?!\s+MessageProperties\s)[^.]*)*\.\s+MessageProperties\s+)(\[.*])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d-%5b-+%3a.0-9%5d*%29%3a%5cs%2b%5b%5e-%5d*%5cs%2b-%5cs%2bBody%3a%5cs%2b%28%5b%5e.%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c.%28%3f!%5cs%2bMessageProperties%5cs%29%5b%5e.%5d*%29*%5c.%5cs%2bMessageProperties%5cs%2b%29%28%5c%5b.*%5d%29&i=2012-05-10+08%3a00%3a00.155%3a+REQUEST+-+Body%3a+%3c%3fxml+version%3d%221.0%22+encoding%3d%22utf-8%22%3f%3e%0d%0a%3cData+xmlns%3axsd%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3axsi%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema-instance%22%3e%0d%0a++%3cfield1%3efi%3c%2ffield1%3e%0d%0a++%3cfield2%3efi2%3c%2ffield2%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fData%3e.+MessageProperties+%5bheaders%3d%7bX_Day%3d20120510%7d%2c+correlationId%3d%5b51%2c+56%2c+98%5d%2c+other%3dblabla%5d&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (use with `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, or when `(?m)` is prepended to the pattern)
- `([0-9]{4}-[- :.0-9]*)` - Group 1:

  - `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[- :.0-9]*` - 0+ digits, `.`, `:`, `-` or space chars
    -`:\s+[^-]*\s+-\s+` - `:`, 1+ whitespace, 0+ chars other than `-`, 1+ whitespaces, `-`, 1+ whitespaces
- `Body:` - a substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([^.]*(?:\.(?!\s+MessageProperties\s)[^.]*)*\.\s+MessageProperties\s+)` - Group 2:

  - `[^.]*(?:\.(?!\s+MessageProperties\s)[^.]*)*` - the unrolled `(?s:.*?)`: any 0+ chars other than `.` followed with 0+ sequences of a `.` not followed with `MessageProperties` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces and then any 0+ chars other than `.`
  - `\.\s+` - a `.` and 1+ whitespaces
  - `MessageProperties` - a substring
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\[.*])` - Group 3: a `[` followed with any 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible, and then a `]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!